# Back to my Mac SSH Timing out, Mac OSX 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

Tags: networking, macos, ssh

I am trying to remotely SSH to my mac using back to my mac with the following command:

```
ssh crut@Rut-Server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com
```

*with 123456789 replaced with my icloud account number

It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Yesterday it didn't work in the morning, but it worked in the evening. Today it doesn't work in the morning.

Here is the verbose output:

```
λ  9:11 (0) ~  |← ssh -vvv crut@Rut-Server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to rut-server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com [fdd5:be09:2866:67f2:587:390b:76ef:2a47] port 22.
debug1: connect to address fdd5:be09:2866:67f2:587:390b:76ef:2a47 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host rut-server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Here is a ping attempt (ran for like 6 mins with no response):

```
λ  9:29 (0) ~  |← ping6 Rut-Server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) fdd5:be09:2866:67f2:8812:6b0c:c48:b246 --> fdd5:be09:2866:67f2:587:390b:76ef:2a47
^C
--- rut-server.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com ping6 statistics ---
443 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Despite it not responding to pings the server is working. It currently hosts a working murmur server. It also appears as available when looking for screen sharing:

```
λ  9:12 (0) ~  |← dns-sd -B _rfb | grep icloud
 9:25:53.929  Add        2   0 123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com. _rfb._tcp.           Rut Server
```

but not for file sharing (despite it being enabled):

```
λ  9:26 (0) ~  |← dns-sd -B _afpovertcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that back to my mac port forwarding was not working correctly because the router was not configured to allow "Plug and Play". Once this was enabled on the router back to my mac was able to correctly port forward, and the ssh connections succeeds each time.

The reason it stopped working was I reset my router and the default settings have "Plug and Play" disabled.